# spring mvc redirect path and all children to another domain

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-redirect

I am trying to work out how to redirect from my webapp to another server, preserving any paths and GET vars.

eg

```
www.myapp.com/foo
foo.com

www.myapp.com/foo/bar
foo.com/bar

www.myapp.com/foo?bar=1
foo.com?bar=1
```

I would idealy just like to use something like

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/foo/**" view-name="redirect:http://foo.com**" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a filter.

infrastructurally this seems to be the simplest way

filter implementation:

```
public class DomainRedirectFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private String destinationDomain;
    private String sourceServletPath;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
             HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
             throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        path = StringUtils.replace(path, getSourceServletPath(), "");
        if (request.getQueryString() != null) {
            path += '?' + request.getQueryString();
        }

        response.setHeader( "Location", getDestinationDomain() + path );
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        response.setHeader( "Connection", "close" );
    }
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>fooDomainRedirectFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.abc.mvc.util.DomainRedirectFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>destinationDomain</param-name>
        <param-value>http://foo.abc.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sourceServletPath</param-name>
        <param-value>/foo</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>fooDomainRedirectFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I needed to add 2 url-patterns to allow for

```
/foo
/foo?id=1
/foo/bar
/foo/bar?id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this as a `Handler` if you are using something like `Jetty`.

```
public class DomainRedirectHandler extends HandlerWrapper {

    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String hostName = request.getHeader("Host");
        if (hostName == null) {
            getHandler().handle(target, baseRequest, request, response);
            return;
        }

        // see if the host header has a domain name that we are redirecting
        hostName = hostName.toLowerCase();
        int index = hostName.indexOf(':');
        if (index >= 0) {
            // cut off the optional port suffix
            hostName = hostName.substring(0, index);
        }

        if (hostName.equals("some.domain.com")) {
            response.sendRedirect("https://some.other.domain.com");
        } else {
            getHandler().handle(target, baseRequest, request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously needs to be before your content handlers in the handler chain to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should probably be done with virtual hosts through Apache.

Here's a link to some documentation:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: ideally we would like to not have to involve apache httpd in this equation

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this with just Spring MVC, since all Spring MVC does is provide a web framework for servlets.  Something would have to be done at the servlet container level (i.e. Tomcat, or a Apache redirect to Tomcat through a proxy).