# Forward Spring HTTP Request

Tags: spring, forward

I have a restful web service written using Spring WebMVC that will mostly be used to orchestrate other services.  In some cases these services are on the same server, in some cases they are not.  I have a few requests (GET and POST) that will be direct pass throughs to another service.  Is there a way to blindly forward all GET and POST data from a request for certain URLs without knowing anything about the data in the request?

Ideally, I would like to be able to say all requests for `http://server1/myService/user/...` should forward to `http://server2/user/...` with all of the GET and POST parameters forwarded with it.

Answer (score 0):

For the services on the same server, if they're being served by the same Spring MVC application, you could use [RedirectViews and/or the "redirect:" prefix](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting).

For those on another server, the best thing I can think of would be to use a servlet filter,  similar to the approach suggested by this post: [spring mvc redirect path and all children to another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568808/spring-mvc-redirect-path-and-all-children-to-another-domain)